# mov machine code crashes on only one machine, both x86, possibly different interpretation?

Tags: assembly, x86

Running the machine code

```
66 50 //push ax
b0 20 //mov al,0x20
a2 20 00 04 11 //mov ds:0x11040020,al // this seems to read 0xffffffffffffffff on one machine
66 58 //pop ax
c3 //ret
```

works on one machine but fails with an access violation trying to read 0xffffffffffffffff when executing the second move on the other.

both machines report report using the amd64 instruction set (checked via win10 environment variable)

none of these instructions seem to be from a new addition to the used instruction set but maybe they
still get interpreted differently?

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is the x86-64 tag appropriate? If so, then `a2 20 00 04 11` is not an instruction, the A2 opcode takes a 64-bit absolute address (rare, but it exists), so it'll steal the 4 following bytes as well. It makes more sense as 32-bit code

Comment: i think that might already be the answer, one machine interpreting it as x86 and the other as x86-64 could produce an error although i'm not sure if it could produce that one

Comment: this whole segment is loaded into an executable memory buffer and the start is called as a function from c++, maybe that context helps

Comment: IIRC Windows shows that "Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" for uses of a non-canonical address, even when not reading from it.

Comment: that seems to be the answer, replacing the four byte address and the four bytes after that with zero bytes changes the access violation to location 0x00000000, thanks for your help! now i just need to find out why it works on the other machine...

Comment: @harold: what a silly choice for a fake address for the non-canonical case; `-1` *is* canonical, in the upper half, and could happen with a combination of bugs.  `0x8000000000000000` would make a lot more sense, being simple but as non-canonical as possible.

Comment: You should have disclosed that you run 32 bit code on one computer and 64 bit code on the other.  It makes a significant difference for any assembly code.

Comment: @PeterCordes or it may as well put the actual address in the error, right? That could have been useful. BTW the same error (access violation reading -1) shows up for uses of unaligned addresses in eg `movaps`, instead of the actual address, but then at least -1 is unaligned

Comment: @harold: That would be idea, but unlike a page-fault #PF where the address in CR2 turns out to be invalid, I'm not sure the OS has easy access to the faulting load/store address (or jump target) on a #GP fault.  (Fun fact: attempts to jump to a non-canonical RIP #GP, with the old RIP as the code address of the fault, rather than faulting on code-fetch with a non-canonical RIP.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one machine interprets the machine code as x86-64 and the other as x86
leading to a crash on the x86-64 machine

Comment: It's not about the machine, it's about what mode it's in.  i.e. how you configure your compiler to build this into a 32-bit executable or a 64-bit executable.  64-bit OSes run 32-bit executables in compat mode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes.  Use `ndisasm -b32` vs. `ndisasm -b64` to see how the same bytes decode differently according to the mode.